# Java ElementType.Parameter not working as expected

Tags: java

I have the following simple code

```
public class User {
    String getSomething (@NotNull Integer age, int name) {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

So when i now call this method by passing null, i expect an error message,as age cannot be passed with null values

```
User u = new User();
u.getSomething(null,1);
```

But the above code passes without any error.Is my understanding of ElementType.PARAMETER used inside @Target annotation in @NotNull incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean by `"the above code passes without any error"` ?  Are you referring to your IDE _not_ giving you a warning with the code `u.getSomething(null,1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, everything is working as expected!

The Java compiler will not check for most annotations. If you have a `@NotNull` annotation on your parameter, the compiler sees it and say, "ok, the parameter has a `@NotNull` annotation" and that's it!

Basically, the `@NotNull` annotation does not do anything as far as the compiler is concerned. It does not mean anything to the compiler. Then why would I bother to add the annotation?

I remember in *Code Complete*, there is a quote:

> Code is written once, but read many many times

The `@NotNull` does not mean anything to the compiler, but it does to *us*, humans! If someone come across your method and sees a `@NotNull`, he/she will know this parameter *cannot* be null. Because some methods can accept null parameters.

Conclusion:

**The annotation does not mean anything to the compiler. It is there for people to read it and know that the parameter cannot be null**.

EDIT:

And you ask, why `u.getSomething(null, 1)` works?

In the method declaration, the first parameter is of type `Integer`. If you look at the docs of `Integer`, it says that it is a class. And a class can have `null` values! So it's perfectly fine!

However, `int` is not a class, it is a primitive data type so it cannot have null values!

**You can think of** `Integer` **as a "nullable"** `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can i make sure that this can be caught during compilation itself ? I don't see any added advantage. Is it more like a comment?

Comment: See my edited post. Does that answer your questions? @rhozet

Comment: Yes thanks the conclusion answers my question.But is there any way that I can get this safety either on compiler or runtime?

Comment: Just use a different IDE. I know Android Studio support this. But I don't think you are developing android apps. I am not sure about others. Maybe one of IntelliJ's? @rhozet